# About using GitHub: repo for every module?

Tags: git, github

If I'm developing javascripts applications and I've got a tons (50-100 - its not a limit) of different plugins/modules that may contain only one JS file, but every module is independent, do I need to have to use github public repository for each module? 
or what is the best strategy to deal with repos that have many independent components?

And one more question: is there a way to group repos on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind modules is to define autonomous *group* of files, not only because they can have their own autonomous history (set of revisions), but also because they could be referenced or deployed independently.

If, in your case, said modules are really only composed of *one* file, going with one module per file might be overkill.
One repo could very well be enough, provided you make sure each commit is about one of those modules (ie modify only one or two file for a particular module).

Unless you have a group of those modules that could be used/deployed independently of the rest of them (in which case 2 Git repos, for two "super-modules", is in order), a simple "modules" repo is enough.